# How to plot mensual boxplots for a specific column in a datetime indexed dataframe?

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I'm really new to python/pandas and I got a problem I just can't figure out.

I got a dataframe which contains several columns with values for a whole year hour by hour. I indexed it using datetime. Something like that (but of course much longer):

```
 d={'date':['01/01/2019 00:00','01/01/2019 01:00','01/01/2019 02:00'],'ex_1':[456,421,478],'ex_2':[243,145,2146],'ex_3':[123,1546,5643]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df=df.set_index(['date'])
```

I want to study this dataframe by plotting boxplots using seaborn or matplotlib, but I want to get mensual boxplots for each month of a year, for a specific column only (so 12 boxes on one graph, for a specific column) and I don't know how to get it...

I tried using df.loc like

```
df.loc['2019-01-01':'2019-01-31']['ex_3']
```

But I can't process it into a boxplot someway, looks like the results is not a dataframe anymore.

I thought may be creating a new dataframe by selecting the specific column I am looking for and creating a new dataframe where each columns will be a month and would contain the specific data of the month, but I can't figured it out neither.

I just don't know which direction to go.

Sorry if it's a dumb question, thanks to everyone who will give me a clue!

Comment: What is a mensual boxplot? Do you mean monthly?

Comment: yes sorry I mean monthly

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column with month (using `df.index.month`), and then plot it with `DataFrame.boxplot`, with `column='ex1'` and `by='month'` parameters:

```
# generate some data
N = 365
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=N),
    'ex1': np.random.random(N) * range(N),
    'ex2': np.random.random(N),
    'ex3': np.random.random(N),
})
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df=df.set_index(['date'])

# plot
df.assign(month=df.index.month).boxplot(
    column='ex1', by='month', figsize=(12, 6))
```

Output:

[image: chart]

Or if you want with `seaborn` + using `index.month_name()` to show month names instead of numbers:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.boxplot(
    x='month', y='ex1',
    data=df.assign(month=df.index.month_name()),
    ax=ax)
```

Output:

[image: seaborn]

Comment: This is so simple i'm ashamed I did'nt found it by myself...
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SonnePer If you wish, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer to signal others that the issue is resolved.